# Changes to peak_local_max in skimage.feature: how do I get the boolean array shaped like the image and not the local feature coordinates?

Tags: python, image-segmentation, scikit-image

Like the title says essentially. Since we the 'indices' keyword is no longer available, how do we pass to the peak_local_max function of skimage.feature that we want the actual array of booleans and not the coordinates? I know I can do it myself by passing the coordinates to some custom function, but I think I'm just missing the new way to do it. Here's the old way I would do it in my code:

```
local_maxi = peak_local_max(distance, indices=False, min_distance=50, labels=dapi_mask_oksize)
```

but this returns an error that the keyword 'indices' is unexpected...

I already tried simply deleting the 'indices' keyword, but now the function seems to work as if it were given 'indices=True' in the old version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following two lines of Python to get the boolean array:

```py
local_maxi = peak_local_max(distance, min_distance=50, labels=dapi_mask_oksize)
peaks_mask = np.zeros_like(distance, dtype=bool)
peaks_mask[local_maxi] = True
```

I think it would be a useful addition to scikit-image to write a helper function in `skimage.util` to do this, because many functions return coordinates:

```py
def coords_to_mask(coords, shape):
    mask = np.zeros(shape, dtype=bool)
    mask[coords] = True
    return mask
```

In the meantime though you can use your own!

Comment: That indeed works! I'm glad that it isn't as straightforward as me just missing out on a keyword that replaced 'indices'. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yeah, if I remember the discussion correctly, it went like: (a) we had a bunch of functions that returned coordinates and others that returned boolean masks, (b) we should unify those function types, (c) the coordinates are a strictly better representation (same info, less memory) (d) ok they should all return coords and users can make masks from that. But a convenience function would still be handy I think!